# React JS with Spring boot API REST

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot

I have a frontend webapp developed with React JS, and a rest API built with Spring boot. When I try to access to API from my react-app I get a 403 Error. My API Rest is deploy in tomcat server.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/fantasy/api/auth/signin 403
PostData.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: We need more information in order to tell you something. First, you could provide us with some log from your frontend app. Then, give us the rest endpoints you are trying to reach. Additionally, tell us the configuration your rest api has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your ReactJs app and Spring Boot app are running under different ports and you did not configure **CORS** in the Spring Rest mapped methods in order enable incoming requests from the host:port on which ReactJs is running:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/user")
public Greeting getUser(){}
```

You can also define it on the Controller itself:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
```

You can also register a separate CORS filter for entire application: [reference](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: In development is a good idea, but if in production my application change port number?

Comment: You then use the CORS filter strategy. In the filter you inject a port number from your properties file which will be different for a dev and prod of course.

Comment: How I could do that?

Comment: I have placed a reference in the answer. Look it up

Comment: CORS filter strategy in my spring boot could be in conflict with Tomcat CORS configuration?

Comment: If you use the embedded spring boot server then it wont be a problem. If you deploy your app on an external Tomcat instance, then you most likely you should choose one place for it

Comment: I have a Tomcat Instance

Comment: I would put that config on spring boot anyway